# Duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality key error 0 Python Error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the follow data set:

[image]

so as you can see, the shape is: 21 rows x 50 columns

So I would like to apply the follow condition:

If any row from "defaultstore"= 1, then the column "FinalSL" column will receive 4 times the value which "FCST:TOTAL" column contains.

So I create the follow function to do this calculation:

```
def SLFinal(defaultStore, fcst):
    if (defaultStore==1):
        return (fcst*4) 
    else:
        return 2

SLFinal(DFstore.iloc[i],FcstList.iloc[i])
```

The function is working, but I would like to apply in my dataset, so I create the follow loops to run each row and storage the data for the "defaultstore" and "FCST:TOTAL" columns:

```
Fcst =  copiedData.iloc[:,45:46]
FcstList = []
lenOfRows2 = len(copiedData)
for i in range(0, lenOfRows2):
   FcstList.append(Fcst.loc[i])

DFstoreList`DFstore = copiedData.iloc[:,46:47]
DFstore

DFstoreList = []
lenOfRows2 = len(copiedData)
for i in range(0, lenOfRows2):
   DFstoreList.append(DFstore.loc[i])
```

And finally, the new list which will contain the values after the function be applied:

```
FinalSLlist1 = []
for i in range(0, lenOfRows2 ):
Rows = []
for j in range(45, 50):
    Rows.append( SLFinal(DFstore[i],FcstList[i]) )
FinalSLlist1.append(Rows)
```

But the folloow error is happening:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    `KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
   2693         # get column
   2694         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2695             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2696 
   2697         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality`
    KeyError: 0
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
```

Just simply use [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method:

```
df['FCST:TOTAL']=df.apply(lambda x:x['FCST:TOTAL']*4 if (x['defaultstore']==1) else 2,1)
```

**OR**

If you are familiar with `numpy` then use [`where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) method as it is more efficient then `pandas` `apply()` method:

```
import numpy as np
df['FCST:TOTAL']=np.where(df['defaultstore']==1,df['FCST:TOTAL']*4,2)
```

Comment: `apply` basically loops over the rows, so not best practice in my opinion.

Comment: yeah It is not much efficient(In terms of speed) for large data.... I was thinking to use numpy's `where()` method but OP doesn't taged numpy so I doesn't consider that OP knows about `numpy`...but added this in answer...thnx  **:)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean indexing and avoid any loops like so:

```
df.loc[df.defaultstore==1, 'FCST:TOTAL'] *= 4
df.loc[df.defaultstore!=1, 'FCST:TOTAL'] = 2
```

It might be helpful to look at the pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) on boolean indexing.